# Getting user categories sub categories

Tags: php, laravel

When user registers then he haves 2 steps.
He must choose categories what is he interest of and then in step two he must choose sub categories of categories what he chose in step one.
In step one he can chose and i save data but in step two i can't get sub categories what he chose.
In my categories table i'm having parent_id column so i for example when he chose category_id one in step two it must show categories where parent_id is 2
I have pivot table CategoryUser where he saves step one user_id and category_id

In controller i don't have nothing ))

```
   public function stepTwoIndex()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('auth/student/step-two')->with('users', $users);
    }
```

In blade

```
   @foreach($users as $user)
            @foreach($user->categories()->where('parent_id', $user->course_category_id)->get() as $category)
            <div class="subcategory-checkboxs row">
                <div class="main-sub col-lg-3">
                    <input class="main-category-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="main-subcategory">
                    <label class="main-category-checkbox" for="main-subcategory">{{ $category->name }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

I'm new in this so it's very hard to me to do this i'm searching all day how to do this but... (

Comment: The blade code shows `$user->course_category_id`. Does this mean a user can only choose 1 'top-level' category of interest?

Comment: I advise you to experiment in your controller function before moving to the blade view. Try and see if you can retrieve the collection you wish, for example with something like: 
`$user = User::find(1); $categories = $user->categories()->where('parent_id', 2)->get(); dd($categories);
`

Comment: Ehh it looks like you posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291998/laravel-sub-categories-seeing-twice) with a lot of similar code. Do you still need an answer to this question?