# Laravel sub categories seeing twice

Tags: php, laravel

When user registers then he haves 2 steps. He must choose categories what is he interest of and then in step two he must choose sub categories of categories what he chose in step one.

```
public function stepTwoIndex()
{
    $users = User::with('categories')->get();
    return view('auth/student/step-two')->with('users', $users);
}
```

blade

```
   @foreach($users as $user)
            @foreach($user->categories as $category)
            @foreach($category->children()->get() as $children)
            <div class="subcategory-checkboxs row">
                <div class="main-sub col-lg-3">
                    <input class="main-category-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="main-subcategory" value="{{$children->id}}" name="categoryId[]">
                    <label class="main-category-checkbox" for="main-subcategory">{{ $children->name }}</label>
                    @foreach($children->children()->get() as $grandChildren)
                    <div class="second-sub">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-subcat" id="sub-subcategory" value="{{$grandChildren->id}}" name="categoryId[]">
                        <label for="sub-subcategory">{{ $grandChildren->name }}</label>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

But problem is that one i choose in step two sub categories and then save it and then i register another user in step two i'm seeing twice sub categories.
Whats i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are just ending up with a big array of category ids for all users in the end, how would you differentiate them? ... also why are you dealing with all the users instead of just one?

Comment: Hello thanks for response i'm new in this so it's hard to me so i have pivot table and i was thinking if i will get in foreach $user->categories i will get current user categories and now i understand that i;m doing it wrong but i really don't know how to do it right way (

Comment: if you only want to do this for the current user then you don't need to retrieve all the users from the database ... if you are using the auth system then the current user (currently authenticated user) is available from it, `$user = Auth::user()`

Comment: Thanks for answer i tried that when u said to me i need current user and yes i use auth system but now i'm getting Attempt to read property "categories" on bool

Comment: you don't have a collection of users now, you have one single model instance; you don't iterate that in a loop ...  remove the `foreach` loop for `$users` since you don't have **users** any more just one **user**

Comment: Thank you so much for help <3 thanks

Comment: Has your question been answered, ManaguaMan? If so, please post the answer so it may help others and people (like me) can see this question does not need more action.